# Invalid JSON data

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, json

I have the following jquery which is invalid:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "heading": "heading goes here 3",
    "content": "<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">content</span> <u><strong>goes </strong></u><span style="color: #ffffff;"><span style="background-color: #ff0000;">here</span></span> 3.</p>"
}
```

I am generating this with asp.net (vb.net) from data stored in a database.  I think I need to somehow escape the double quotes within the content section of the json data.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are  you creating this json data manually?

Comment: @santosh, yes.  So basically, the bit which goes into the "content": section can be stored in a variable for escaping if escaping is what is needed.

Comment: @oshirowanen:There is an inbuilt class in .net framework named JavaScriptSerializer for creating json data then why you are creating it manually?

Comment: It's the first time I have heard of this.

Comment: Check this link .http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/javascriptserializer-example/

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but, this does not look appropriate for my needs.  I need to somehow escape the json data before sending it back to clientside.  Then unescape (if required) so I can use it in javascript/jquery.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer will escape double quotes with a backslash automatically.  You should definitely use it instead of manually generating JSON.  Unless your data has cyclic references, JSS is quite robust.

Comment: @Dave Ward, any good vb.net tutorials showing how to get data from a database, then serialize it before returning it at the end of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out

```
mystring.replace("""","\""")
```

replaces all " with \"

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes for the style attribute.

Comment: I can't, because the data in the "content": section is generated by ckeditor.  I don't know if ckeditor can be set to use single quotes instead of double quotes.